# Wp Rest Api Custom End point

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Im trying to add a custom end point to my wp-rest api the latest version. I have this already but the one with the slug param at the end does not work.. Does any one know why.. would be great if anyone could help..

```
     register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/guestmix', array(
        array(
            'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_guestmixes' )
        ),
        'schema' => array( $this, 'get_public_item_schema' )
    ) );

    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/guestmix/(?P<slug>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_guestmix'
    ) );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i guess it because you used `d` metacharacter for regex `(?P<slug>\d+)` that's mean for digit, please try use `S` instead.
The code should look like this

```
register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/guestmix/(?P<slug>\S+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_guestmix'
) );
```

this is cheat sheet for reference http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: I have been looking for  cheat sheet for WP rest routes for some time now and by chance came across this page (it may be because I used edge to sear h instead of chrome) but finally I have  chance at finding the solution to my url regex, I hate regex enough (despite the 'wow thats impressive' thoughts I get now and then)  my problem was that my url needed to be url encoded and had 19 sections - yes I know...

Comment: If only Wordpress documentation cared to explain which metacharacters we can use.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer works for me, though I implemented the regular expression slightly differently, following a 2019 gist, that covers different url/slug-structure scenarios.

```
register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', '/guestmix/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_guestmix'
) );
```

Hope this helps