# Cron job not working when try to access a wordpress url in cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to add a cron job directly from the server for a WordPress website.
But it's not working

```
URL FOR CRON:
https://bidbay.co.ke/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action
```

if I directly access the above URL in browser its working fine, but when I run it through cron job, it's not working

```
CRON :
wget -O - -q https://bidbay.co.ke/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action
```

Also when i run cron job after putting a php file, its working fine...

please guide...

Comment: did you try this way   `curl -s "https://bidbay.co.ke/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action"`

Comment: It's not working, because you are not authorize.

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "not working" in code, any more than a mechanic can fix a car that is "not working", without any other information about the problem. How is it not working? What exactly happens when you run the code? Have you tested the `wget` command directly from a terminal? What was the result? As Dmitry suggests, I would guess it's because that admin page requires you to log in before you can do anything, and your cron/terminal session will not be logged in.

Comment: @Dmitry how can i authorize to make this call in cron jobs?

Comment: @DeDevelopers you can try create rest api endpoint - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024437/wp-rest-api-custom-end-point

Comment: @Dmitry if i run directly above url its functioning fine, but when i run cron its not working... what could be the reason.

Comment: @ThusharaDahanayake not working.. if i run a cron from normal php (https://bidbay.co.ke/test_cron.php) cron job is working fine, but not for this wordpress why?